# Rails RESTful Routing With '/' and Slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, link-to

I am looking to do something similar a wordpress slug where I have a URL like this while maintaining RESTful routing:

```
http://foo.com/blog/2009/12/04/article-title
```

The reason I am interested in keep RESTFUL routing is that I am unable to use many plugins because I am using custom routes.

I have already done the RESTful appearance with:

```
map.connect   '/blog/:year/:mon/:day/:slug',
              :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show',
                :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/,
                :day => /\d{2}/, :slug => /.+/,
                :requirements => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/, :slug => /.+/ }
```

In order to write the links, I had to write custom link_to helpers to generate the proper URLs.  I really would like to make this RESTful and have the link_to post_path( @post ) yield the URL above and the link_to edit_post_path(@post) ...article-title/edit

I also have :has_many => [:comments] and I would that to work as well.  The link_to that I have tried looks like this:

```
 'posts', :action => 'show', :year => recent_post.datetime.year.to_s,
            :month => sprintf('%.2d', recent_post.datetime.mon.to_i),
            :day => sprintf('%.2d', recent_post.datetime.mday.to_i),
            :slug => recent_post.slug %>
```

and yields this (which isn't what I want):

```
http://foo.com/posts/show?day=30&month=11&slug=welcome-to-support-skydivers&year=2009
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is it even possible to accomplish this?

Comment: To be more specific as to the reasoning, I am trying to use a sitemap generator plugin that uses the routes generated through the map.resources section of the routes.rb.  I am trying to avoid having to extend the plugin to handle completely custom routes. I already have the helpers written to generate the links themselves. I am curious as to whether its possible to use route-generated urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not working because you're not using a custom route. I do this all of the time. I simply setup a simple custom route:

```
map.present_page '/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug',
          :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
present_page_path(:year => 2009, 
                  :month => "December", 
                  :day => "13", 
                  :slug => "just-an-example")
```

The reason you're getting a query string is most likely because rails isn't making the connection to your route for whatever reason. Using a named route explicitly tells rails to use that route. Let me know if that solves it for you!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  Using your example, I went one step further (because generating my :year, :month, :day wasn't straight forward) and added a method to my model called named_route_generator which returns a hash of the values. Now in the view, I just do: show_url(post.named_route_generator).  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, things like `present_page_url(@post)` or `url_for(@post)` do not work using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I went about this...

First, I'm not trying to use the route-generated url method. Also, I'm not going to the same extent as you in terms of checking formatting of the date parameters. Since I'm auto-generating the datestamps and the URL creation, I'm not concerned about format validity, I'm simply formatting a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object.

Let's start with the relevant route:

```
  map.post_by_date 'content/:year/:month/:day/:slug', 
                  :controller => 'posts',
                  :action     => 'show_by_date_slug'
```

Since I didn't want to worry about argument formatting, or repetition, I created a helper method and included the helper in the relevant controller:

```
  def pubdate_slug_url(post)
    year   = post.published_on.strftime('%Y')
    month  = post.published_on.strftime('%m')
    day    = post.published_on.strftime('%d')

    url    = "/" + ["content", year, month, day, post.slug].join("/")

    return url
  end
```

Finally, in my view, I simply call the method, passing in my Post object:

```
  <h2><%= link_to post.headline, pubdate_slug_url(post) %></h2>
```

I end up with a url like: http://wallscorp.us/content/2009/12/06/links

Cheers.