# Whats the meaning of :slug in route.rb (ruby on rails). How its mapped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whats the meaning of :slug in routes.rb (ruby on rails). How its mapped?

Answer (score 4):

As with any other name, `:param` syntax means that this part of the url corresponds to a parameter named `param`.

So, taking an example of how SO urls are defined, we can observe the following route:

```
map.connect "/questions/:id/:slug", :controller => "questions", :action => "show"
```

And when you come to an url of the form `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082982/whats-the-meaning-of-slug-in-route-rb-ruby-on-rails-how-its-mapped`, it will be handled by `QuestionsController#show` with the `params` hash `{ :id => "3082982", :slug => "whats-the-meaning-of-slug-in-route-rb-ruby-on-rails-how-its-mapped" }`.

Comment: So for example, if I give like this 
map.root :controller => "pages", :action => 'show', :slug => "**homepage**"

what will happen?

Comment: this will only make all requests to your root route to `PagesController#show` with params `{ :slug => "**homepage**" }`. You're probably misunderstanding the concept of how slugs work in rails. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871267/rails-restful-routing-with-and-slugs , and generally, search rules)